# Cannot 'getObject' from S3 bucket - policy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've spent 10+ hours on this (har har I know), but simply cannot get to the bottom of it.

---

## Update - See bottom of QN

---

## Scenario

I have an app that allows users to upload an object to S3 and then download it at a later date whenever they like.

Using the policies below, uploading works just fine, the getObject call, however does not.

### IAM user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried a bunch of other, finer grained policies above as well, but none have worked, hence, just to get it working, I'm trying to set a user policy that grants root level access to AWS with the aim to fine-tune it from there.

### Bucket policy

I don't believe any bucket policy is required for this, however, for what it is worth, I have tried no policy as well as the below policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AWSGeneratedPolicyId",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RandomSidGeneratedHere",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::305492142848:user/username-this-line-copy-pasted-from-AWS-IAM-console"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Function calling getObject:

```
const params = {
        Bucket: 'bucketname',
        Key: 'objectkey',
    };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

## Outcome and error message

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>FC1698B03B31AF06</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    ZDDPr+WHCAnoAY/FyGTZA3iv8+L9R0r5CYGI5Owf/DOsItmsU5BSEtD8qXAZc4UHSgSqv2zneH4=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

## Troubleshooting:

I know that the credentials are correct because uploading works fine
I know that the 'test' hard-coded function above is correct (in terms of bucket name and key) because If I change the bucket to be 'public' for read, then the function call to `getObject` works fine

**The above would imply that the IAM user in question does not have the permission to `getObject` - but as per the user policy applied, what more permissions are needed??**

Any suggestions much appreciated (note - I've looked through the forums and seen similar questions but none of the answers seem to be working for me)

## Update

On a whim, I changed the function to do this:

```
s3.listBuckets({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    console.log(data);
}
```

AND instead of listing all the expected buckets, I am getting a list of buckets from a different account. This is happening in spite of the below being the code at the top:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_KEY;
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET;
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

This weirdness now makes sense - the buckets listed are those on a different AWS account entirely (one I created when experimenting with the serverless.com framework).

#### Hypothesis

The local server is somehow fixed in its configuration and the configuration properties being set in the code are not having an impact.

I can confirm this is the case by deploying the exact same code to an actual server where it works as expected (i.e. the getObject call works fine)

#### Revised question:

How does one clear the 'cache' or whatever it is in the terminal that is holding on to these values? Is this a bug with iTerm/serverless.com (if so I can take the necessary steps in...). If it is not a bug and is instead the expected behaviour, how should this be avoided in the future?

Comment: If you upload an object via the Amazon S3 console, can your code successfully download it? Can you show us your code for uploading the object? Specifically, it would be interesting to see what you set for `ACL`, which should normally be `bucket-owner-full-control`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Uploading via the console has the same issue (access denied message). If I upload via the console and provide public read access then (as expected), it works. Code used to do the upload - it's basically using React with EvaporateJS (https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS). I guess the important points of note here are that the access key ID and the secret Access key are environmental variables being reused in both the upload and download functions (so there is no mismatch there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as per the updated question - and the clue from the `listObjects` function call, I figured out that at server runtime, AWS config was ignoring my credentials in favour of the credentials stored in the path: `~/.aws/credentials`.

## Solution:

Delete the `credentials` file mentioned and all works as it should...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with this policy and worked.

Try give to access all AWS IAM account with * (just to discard) below my bucket policy, another thing, why do you use expire property? anyway try delete that line.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AWSGeneratedPolicyId",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RandomSidGeneratedHere",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, when you upload the picture, check out that you assigning ACL property:

```
S3.putObject({
            Bucket: process.env.bucket,
            Body: imageContent.body,
            Key: `${key}`,
            ACL:'public-read'
        })
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Cheers for the answer! But providing 'public-read', while it will work, will make the bucket contents insecure. The objects need to be available only to my server.

Forgive the expire property - it is there for the getSignedUrl function (which is having the same issues) - not relevant to the 'getObject'. I forgot to remove it from the question and will update.

Comment: Ok , then you must grants access to the photos bucket through EC2 instance.

checkout this link:

[Read More](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

Comment: No the server is not running on EC2. And the issue is present regardless of where the server is running.

Comment: do you setting up environment variable  (aws credentials) on the server?